# How to switch position of 2 divs using only CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is [what I've created](http://jsfiddle.net/LBTHw/embedded/result/). I'm setting `class='handHeld'` to `<body>` in iPad, based on which
the optionsWrapper and #container should switch positions using CSS classes I've defined at the bottom in jsfiddle.net.

```
.handHeld div.optionsWrapper { ... }
.handHeld div#container { ... }
```

to something like this: [image]

How to achieve that using CSS only? Please note that first 3 rows (green, gray and blue) may
not be present always so I can not grab their height statically to position `div.optionsWrapper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `optionsWrapper` is a child of `container`, you cannot do this via CSS. You must have the two divs side by side as start. Then, one of the two divs must have an absolute height (in px). And last but not least, the `position` style of their parent must be `relative`. Having the parent relative, setting `absolute left/top:0` on optionsWrapper should put it in top left corner of container.

Easiest illustrated via inline styles here:

#### with no 'handheld', your standard styling (but with options 'outside')

```
<div style="position: relative">
   <div id="container">   stretching? lots of contents   </div>
   <div id="optionsWrapper"> left right </div>
</div>
```

#### when body has the 'handheld' class:

```
<div style="position: relative; overflow:hidden:">
   <div id="container" 

          style="margin-top: 50px; z-index:9;">

         stretching? lots of contents
   </div>
   <div id="optionsWrapper" 

          style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:99;">

      left right 
   </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QzQCt/

Comment: You solution is broken but accepted. I tweaked it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/LBTHw/1/

Comment: its only the CSS technique, you must figure out absolute heights yourself in the JS, thx :)

Comment: Thats what I did without using JS code. Just wrapped `.content` inside  `.contentWrapper` as you suggested above.